# How To Enable Block Inside Fifty Different Sections Without Copying Meta Code?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

I am developing a Shopify Theme. The structure I have now is (excerpt):

**Snippets**

custom-message-snippet

**Sections**

custom-message-section

welcome-page-a-section

welcome-page-b-section

**Templates**

welcome-page-a-template

welcome-page-b-template

...

Custom message snippet uses settings that are in the custom-message-section, that is:

a) message

b) header text

I'd like for users to be able to add custom-message-snippet to welcome-page-a and welcome-page-b in a way that settings for both are different.

I can not render section 'custom-message-section" inside welcome pages because it is not possible (and a workaround is nasty).

There are fifty welcome pages. Every welcome page is totally different.

My question is:

How to allow users to use custom-message-snippet in all welcome pages without copying and pasting custom-message-page setting schema to each and every welcome page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine `custom-message-section` to `custom-message-snippet`

combine `welcome-page-\w+-template` to `welcome-page-template`, you only need to have one template and schema set, the user will control the sections in schema selection.

in **template**, use schema to select the page-content; this, defined by a bunch of if-else /switch statement.

```
{% section "welcome-page-custom-message-section" %}
{% section "welcome-page-content" %}
```

in **welcome-page-custom-message-section**

```
{% render "custom-message-snippet" with "string from welcome-page-section schema " %}
```

create checkbox select schema for custom message to appear or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do I understand you correctly that I should have:

1) one template that has a setting to choose "layout"
2) depending on that setting I should render appropriate section/s (with if/elses)

? Is it ok if sections are very different between each other?

Comment: 1. yes, user only need to have one template that can choose which section to add; you can set up default.  2.  yes. 3.  yes, all that code is separated in different section file.

Comment: more infor https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/templates/json-templates

Answer (score 1):

Short: You can't.

Long: Using storefront 2.0, you end you having blocks, which can be added manually to any template.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What is Storefront? Is it Shopify?

Comment: the correct term should be online-store 2.0 https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/shopify-online-store  ; storefront is a shopify API that can use fetch to retrieve multiple information so you can generate your store anywhere; with React, for example

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you have a little knowledge of Node.js and you're using the Shopify CLI.
Check the solution here: [Shopify Section / Block Schema In A Separate File. It is possible](https://share-docs.clickup.com/14282782/p/h/dkw0y-10187/d3a845381ed311b/dkw0y-10187)

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer! However: the answer would've been more useful if you provided a few excerpts of the article you linked to, because if that article was to disappear for whatever reason, there'd be no clue on how to solve the problem at all.